# ReportGenerator does not show code coverage for individual files

Tags: docker, azure-pipelines, code-coverage, .net-6.0, reportgenerator

I have a .Net 6 application which has 3 Test Projects. I have Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline which shows the code coverage report.

In a Dockerfile, I run tests for individual project and generate a code coverage report using ReportGenerator tool. Here is my `DockerFile`

```
# Install Report Generator Tool
RUN dotnet tool install dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool --tool-path /tools

# Run tests for individual test projects to generate test and code coverage report
RUN dotnet test "PreAdviceGeneration.Presentation.UnitTests/PreAdviceGeneration.Presentation.UnitTests.csproj" \
    --logger "trx;LogFileName=PreAdviceGeneration.Presentation.UnitTests.trx" \
    --results-directory /TestResults \
    /p:CoverletOutput=/TestResults/presentation/ /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura 
RUN dotnet test "PreAdviceGeneration.Application.UnitTests/PreAdviceGeneration.Application.UnitTests.csproj" \
    --logger "trx;LogFileName=PreAdviceGeneration.Application.UnitTests.trx" \
    --results-directory /TestResults \
    /p:CoverletOutput=/TestResults/application/ /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura 
RUN dotnet test "PreAdviceGeneration.Infrastructure.IntegrationTests/PreAdviceGeneration.Infrastructure.IntegrationTests.csproj" \
    --results-directory /TestResults \
    --logger "trx;LogFileName=PreAdviceGeneration.Infrastructure.IntegrationTests.trx" \
    /p:CoverletOutput=/TestResults/infrastructure/ /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura

# Convert multiple cobertura reports into one and publish the result to the target directory.
RUN /tools/reportgenerator "-reports:/TestResults/**/coverage.cobertura.xml" \
    "-targetdir:/TestResults/coveragereport" \
    "-reporttypes:Cobertura" \
    "-classfilters:-Models.*;-Constants.*;-Configurtation.*;-Program.cs;-SpmContext.cs" \
    "-verbosity:Verbose"
```

In the azure pipeline, I first copy test report and the code coverage report stored in the container into the pipeline's host agent.
Then run the `PublishCodeCoverageResults@1` task. Here is the azure pipeline.

```
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: Copy test results to the agent
    inputs:
      script: |
        echo 'Default directory is::: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        echo 'Source directory is:::: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
        echo 'ArtifactStagingDirectory is:::: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

        docker build -f $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile --target build -t $(Build.BuildId) .
        docker create -ti --name testcontainer $(Build.BuildId)
        docker cp testcontainer:/TestResults ./TestResults
        docker rm -fv testcontainer

  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    displayName: 'Publish test results'
    inputs:
      testResultsFormat: 'VSTest'
      testResultsFiles: '**/*.trx'
      searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TestResults'
      failTaskOnFailedTests: true

  - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
    displayName: 'Publish code coverage results'
    inputs:
      codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
      summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TestResults/coveragereport/*.xml'
```

The issue I am facing is that, although it generates the following code coverage report,
[image]

if I dive into individual file, I see error as `File '/src/PreAdviceGeneration.Application/MappingProfiles/DomainItemTopicMessageProfile.cs' does not exist (any more).` See the screenshot below
[image]

PS: Worth mentioning that I cannot install the ReportGenerator [plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Palmmedia.reportgenerator) in AzureDevops.

Comment: When I run it locally, it works as expected. Wondering since the source code exist in the container instead of the host agent that it cannot find the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build stage of my docker file had WORKDIR as `/app`. As tests are run in app directory, the ReportGenerator sets source location starting with `/app/....`. When the report is copied in Azure Host, and published, it tries to find the source code with the path `/app/...`.
The source code in the Azure host agent lies at the location, `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` which is `/home/vsts/work/1/s`. Hence the published report cannot find the source file.

Hence to have the consistent path across docker image and Azure Host, I updated the WORKDIR of the build stage of Dockerfile to `/home/vsts/work/1/s` and now I am able to see the report for individual files.

My Docker file now looks like:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /home/vsts/work/1/s
COPY . .

.........
```